# Getting error module not found can't resolve path from tsconfig.base.json issue in Angular storybook build

Tags: angular, angular-storybook

My storybook library is not reading the path from tsconfig.base.json. And keep giving this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Below is my main.js file.

[image]

we have recently upgraded to Angular 13. But it's not confirmed that upgrade is the issue.
while it was working in Angular 12. what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention that we are using nrwl Mono repo.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the original text to your question.